# Banco de dados relacional sem integridade referencial

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Comprei um software para fazer algumas modificações e implementar melhorias. No entanto, quando fui avaliar o banco, não possui integridade referencial, ou seja, as tabelas não estão interligadas. As regras de negócios estão perfeitas. Do ponto de vista de qualidade de software isso é muito ruim? O wordpress, por exemplo, não usa integridade referencial.

Answer (score 0):

Depende. Se os programadores do software abusaram da falta de integridade referencial, conscientes dela ou não, então é ruim, porque você vai ter dados inconsistentes no seu banco que talvez não saberá consertar. Senão não é tão ruim assim, mas ainda é ruim, e recomenda-se aplicar a integridade onde souber para evitar problemas maiores no futuro. Ou então deixa assim, e torce pra não dar nenhum problema (contando com a sorte). Pra que pára-quedas? /s

Comment: Mas o wordpress, por exemplo, não usa integridade referencial. E olha que os desenvolvedores do wordpress são muito bons. O que acha a respeito? Tudo depende de uma perspectiva de software?

Comment: Já trabalhei com banco sem integridade e não teve problemas, mas eu particularmente não arriscaria.

Comment: Já vi também casos onde não foi usado para "melhorar a velocidade" do banco mas se "garantia" a integridade dos dados pela aplicação, eu particularmente prefiro usar quando possível e ou necessario